# How can i consult my transaction history via Bitcoind/JsonRPCClient?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, history

If you go to your Bitcoin-qt wallet, there is a list of all the transactions you have ever made, you can even see the transactions detals.

Well, i cant find the way to get from bitcoind that same list. I want to know the transaction id of every transaction ever made in my wallet, there should be a way to get it since Bitcoin-qt has that list. Anyone knows?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wow, sorry guys, for some reason i checked like 3 times all of the Bitcoind commands and didn't see it, but here it is:

```
listtransactions [account] [count=10] [from=0]
```

Returns up to [count] most recent transactions skipping the first [from] transactions for account [account]. If [account] not provided will return recent transaction from all accounts.

Comment: Also, you can use "*" as account, if you need to provide the other arguments but still want all accounts.

Comment: I can't find anywhere in the documentation that sending "*" will bring all accounts, what if i have an account named * ?